# My javascript file is not loaded. (Drupal7)

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

My javascript file is not working. I can't see it in the inspector. I think it doesn't loaded at all.

There is missing something in my file?

This is my whole js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".sf-main-menu li").click(function() {



  /* Add the slider movement */

  // what tab was pressed
  var whatTab = $(this).index();

  // Work out how far the slider needs to go
  var howFar = 160 * whatTab;

  $(".slider").css({
    left: howFar + "px"
  });


});

});
```

I added it to the .info file.

The code should working, I got it from [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/eNpXQz). I think maybe something is missing in the file, some declaration, like doctype in html.

(This code moves a slider (which is a line under menuitems.)

DOM:
[image]

Comment: How did you include this in your html? did you included jQuery before this? what is  _.info_ file?

Comment: Hello, please try to write a more significant title to increase interest in people here around. And I further suggest you to improve the descriptions adding significant details about your case. For example, the checks you already made, what you think the code should do and when.

Comment: @Sankar Raj I added this js file to html with info file ( in drupal7) other jquery what I made is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! :)

I wrote:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Now it is working.

(I am not sure why I got so many minus points for my question...)

Answer (score 0):

first question, is jquery loaded befor the script?

And second, you should wrap it in a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(function() {
  $(".sf-main-menu li").click(function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

This will check if the entire DOM is loaded, because otherwise chances are you are binding an event-listener to a DOMNode that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I modified my post as you said. And my code, but it doesn't work.
jquery loaded before the script? How should I know?